# Web-scraping of mobile apps?

Tags: web-scraping, screen-scraping

Is there any program/library available that can scrape the contents of an mobile apps' screen?

The goal is to have a nice data structure for the Instagram "Following" feed.

Comment: Is there any specific reason to do it on mobile app and not in web?

Comment: Instagram's web client has no "Following" feed.

Comment: What about using the Instagram's API? check: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/

Comment: That's not it. Instagram's app has a live feed of stuff that's happening, like "ABC liked XYZ's post"

Answer (score 1):

There is not complete solution for it, but it can be achieved by using different software like bruipsuit, postman, binaries, Amulators or rooted android devices  and man in the middle attack technique.
If you need to achieve this you have to make a setup to interrupt the request to the app and decode data from the request.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I've done it for a few apps (not instagram) with screen-scraper.com. I set the phone to use wifi only, and logged the requests on the router. I used that to emulate the request the app makes. Usually it's a pretty easy HTTP request, and they can be touchy about the user agent. Then the data is almost always XML or JSON.

Answer (score 0):

With appium you can write test for mobile app, using uiatomatorviewer find the elements address and then try to use norest=true capability you can scrap data.
https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/automate-native-app-on-android-device/